# Adding seconds with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp

The idea is that I need to get end_date from the Auction via this model, which is inside a database, in MySQL timestamp format (I use phpmyadmin, if it matters, ex. 2018-11-14 04:58:07). So when I get the end_date, the idea is to increment it by few seconds (ex. 10 seconds) via Carbon addSeconds() function and then write it again into the DB. Here is the controller where it's done and my Auction model.
What happens is that i get the FatalThrowableError 'Call to a member function addSeconds() on integer'. I played around quite a lot and can't seem to find right format for the secs2 variable.

Auction.php

```
public $id;
public $name;
public $descript;
public $price;
public $pic;
public $end_date;
public $offers;
public $offered_by;

    public function get(){
    $result =
        DB::table('auctions')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('id', '=', $this->id)
            ->first();
    return $result;
}

    public function increment($id){
    $result =
        DB::table('auctions')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([
                'offers' => DB::raw('offers + 1'),
                'end_date' => $this->end_date
            ]);
    return $result;
}
```

AuctionController.php

```
    public function offer($id, Request $request){
    $auction = new Auction();
    $auction->id = $id;

    $secs = $auction->get()->end_date;
    $secs2 = strtotime($secs);
    $secs2->addSeconds(120);

    $auction->end_date = $secs2;
    //dd($secs2);

    $auction->increment($id);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use `addSeconds` method, you can't convert your time into number first..
ex:

```php
Carbon::parse($auction->get()->end_date)
      ->addSeconds(120)
      ->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Was that a proposed solution? When I try your version i get 'Call to a member function addSeconds() on string'

Comment: can you print out the result of `Carbon::parse($auction->get()->end_date)` ?

Comment: this is dumped result:
Carbon @1542171487 {#199 ▼
  date: 2018-11-14 04:58:07.0 UTC (+00:00)
}

Comment: So apparently that made it add seconds the right way.

Comment: Thank you. Carbon::parse($auction->get()->end_date)->addSecond(120) is the solution. It works now.

Comment: You should accept this answer if it does answer your question